# Why some files in data directory of a Postgresql cluster are symlink to files of another cluster?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I did use `pg_upgrade`.

I had a cluster of Postgresql with version 9.6 on my machine, and then I did start another cluster with version of v12. Each of them had separate data directories, in a directory scheme like this:

```
./postgresql/
├── 12
│   └── main
└── 9.6
    └── main
```

Then I turned off the 9.6 cluster and started using the v12 one. But now, by accident, I found out that some of the files in the `base` directory of the v12 cluster are not files, but symlinks to files in `base` directory of the 9.6 one; For example:

```
./postgresql/12/main/base/16401/35093 -> ./postgresql/9.6/main/base/16402/35093
```

Why is it so? And, more importantly, how is it so?! I mean, I thought that the files inside `base` directory are so internal to each DB that this could not be possible at all.

And, can I do something to disable using symlinks?

Comment: Urgh. Danger Will Robinson!

Comment: did you run any pg_upgrade ?

Comment: @ShiwanginiShishulkar yes I did use pg_upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a `pg_upgrade` with the `-k` option, and these are not symbolic links, but hard links.

If you didn't manage to start the old cluster after `pg_upgrade` everything is fine. You just forgot to remove the old cluster after upgrading. Do that right now:

```bash
rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
```

If you use `-k`, the upgrade process doesn't copy, but link the files. That makes the upgrade much faster, but renders the old cluster unusable.

Comment: I did use `pg_upgrade` and the older cluster isn't running, but anyway I don't like it the way it is! Isn't there any other option than dumping and init again? Because it's a large DB

Comment: and, If it so bad that I should dump & init again, why the hell does `pg_upgrade` does that?!

Comment: the old cluster isn't running after the upgrade, but I still don't understand: the only option to turn those hard links to normal files is to delete the source of links?

Comment: Ok, if you never started the cluster, there is no problem. Remove the old data directory as my updated answer says.